# PrintToPDF not working in headless Chrome 60

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, pdf-generation, google-chrome-devtools, centos7

I'm trying to experiment with PDF printing via headless Chrome. This is the error I'm dealing with:

> (node:6761) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): **Error: PrintToPDF is not implemented**

Node.js package:

```
html-pdf-chrome
```

Dependencies:

```
✔ "chrome-remote-interface": "^0.23.1"  (v0.23.2 installed)   
✔ Chrome 59  (v60 beta installed)
```

Driver script:

```
const htmlPdf = require('html-pdf-chrome');
const html = '<p>Hello, world!</p>';
const options = {
    port: 9222, // port Chrome is listening on
};
htmlPdf.create(html, options).then((pdf) => pdf.toFile('test.pdf'));
```

Chrome 60 is installed and running in headless mode:

```
> google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 60.0.3112.24 beta
```

I've tracked down the code sections that calls `Page.printToPDF` which is where the error is raised:

```
const CDP = require("chrome-remote-interface");
...
const { Page } = client;
...
// https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF
const pdf = yield Page.printToPDF(options.printOptions);
```

I am able to perform other advertised functions like `Page.captureScreenshot` without fail.

How to get `Page.printToPDF` to perform as advertised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I create the headless Chrome command in PHP to run Chrome under the `apache` user:

```
private $headlessChromeCmd = [
    '$(which google-chrome)',
    '--headless',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--hide-scrollbars',
    '--remote-debugging-port=%u',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update',
    '--disable-background-networking',
    //'--disable-extensions', <-- This was the problem
    '--disable-translate',
    '--disable-sync'
];

...

// Launch Chrome in a non-blocking background process
$cmd = sprintf(implode(' ', $this->headlessChromeCmd), $port) . ' < /dev/null >"'. $this->chromeStdoutFile . '" 2>&1 & echo $!;';

// For brevity without capturing stdout, stderr nor response codes
shell_exec($cmd);
```

The CLI param `--disable-extensions` was the culprit. Chrome's PDF viewer, needed to generate PDFs, is one of the extensions disabled by this parameter. Mystery solved.